# AngularJS controller $scope not working inside ng-if directive

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a login form but for some reason the data is not being binded between the HTML and the controller. This is my code:

#### home.html

```
<div ng-if="loggedIn">
    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
    <p>Some other welcome content...</p>
</div>

<form ng-if="!loggedIn">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
    <button type="submit" data-ng-click="login()">Login</button>
</form>
```

***Note:** labels, classes and ids ommited for brevity.*

#### controller.js

```
myapp.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$log', function(scope, log) {
    scope.loggedIn = false;
    // ADDED CODE HERE

    scope.login = function() {
        // Dummy validation
        if(scope.username == 'admin' && scope.password == 'admin') {
            scope.loggedIn = true;
        };
        log.log('username: ' + scope.nombreUsuario);
        log.log('password: ' + scope.password);
        log.log('is logged in: ' + scope.loggedIn);
    };
}]);
```

#### config.js

```
myapp.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function(locationProvider, routeProvider) {
    // Remove default '!' from URL
    locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })
    // ... some other .when ...
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

When I execute this, the console output of the `login` function is

```
username: undefined
password: undefined
is logged in: false
```

However, if I add the following to the controller in the `//ADDED CODE HERE` section

```
scope.username = 'admin';
scope.password = 'admin';
```

the console gives me the following:

```
username: admin
password: admin
is logged in: true
```

i.e. it's working correctly. So the question is: why my view (`ng-model="..."`) doesn't bind to the controller's scope? what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Where is your `ng-controller="HomeController"` placed?

Comment: It's in the `myapp.config` section, I can tell for sure that it's working correctly

Comment: Could you add more codes? Let us see in which way your controller is binded to your view.

Comment: @lin, please check the update. Let me know if you need more info. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just access the `$parent` scope `$parent.username`, `$parent.password` and you will be fine like in this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urwby76y/)**.

Some directives like `ng-if` does create a child scope so you need to access the parent scope. (Thx @FrankModica). E.g. if you are using `ng-show` or `ng-hide`you dont need to access a `$parent` scope (**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwLjgych/)** which uses `ng-show`).

```
<form ng-if="!loggedIn">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="$parent.username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="$parent.password">
    <button type="submit" data-ng-click="login()">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This will work, but is not recommended because it is brittle. If the page is updated and new scopes are added you can run into issues.

Comment: Great!, worked perfectly. But why do I need to access the parent scope? (what's the parent scope anyway? It's the first time I need to use it) Thank you so much

Comment: I'll take into account the posible issue you mention. I've seen now the explanation in the edit. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Try binding to an object:

```
$scope.myForm = {
    userName: '',
    password: '',
    // ...
};

<input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="myForm.username">
```

Because of prototypal inheritance, `ng-model` is initially reading from the parent scope (your controller). But as soon as the user types, `ng-model` ends up writing to the child scope created by `ng-if`, which inherits from the parent scope. If you bind to an object (not a primitive), you can be sure you will be reading and writing from the same place.